# How to remove "Have no fear, help is near!" from 404 error page?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, magento-community

I am newbie in Magento development. I want to remove "Have no fear, help is near! There are many ways you can get back on track with Magento Demo Store." from 404 error page in my site. How can I remove the line from the site and adding custom content to that page ?

Comment: Also, you can fix the "Oops, my bad" part as well. Our customers found it to be Hipsterish and unprofessional and complained about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 page is a simple CMS page. Go to `CMS->Pages` in your admin panel, look for the 404 page and edit it.
The default 404 page title is `404 Not Found`.